# Getting error " Hadoop Release '%s' is an invalid/unsupported release. Valid entries are in 2.6.0"

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mongodb-hadoop

I am working on `mongodb-hadoop` connector. For this process, i am building mongodb adapter,after edited `build.sbt` file,i am trying to building adapter like `./sbt` package then i am getting error

> Hadoop Release '%s' is an invalid/unsupported release

My Hadoop version

```
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.2
```

My build.sbt file

```
name := "mongo-hadoop"    
organization := "org.mongodb"
hadoopRelease in ThisBuild := "2.6.0"
```

Please help me how can i fix it ?